# How to allow vpn clients to access lan servers

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking, proxmox

I need some help understanding how to allow the vpn clients to access servers that are on the "intranet".

I have one dedicated/physical server at ovh(if that matters) with 4 additional ips. The OS installed is proxmox and I have two network devices (their type is 'Linux bridge'). One has the server's public ip assigned(vmbr0), the other one(vmbr1) has the ip 172.20.0.1 with 255.252.0.0 as netmask.

I created some virtual machines that have only the vmbr1 assigned to them. I can happily ping between these machines. I also get access to the internet from these machines just as if they were behind my home router. If it matters, on 172.20.0.2 I have a dhcp server and on 172.20.0.3 and 172.20.0.4 I have two dns servers.

I created another virtual machine that has both vmbr0 and vmbr1 assigned to it. I have configured one of the additional public ips on vmbr0 and I can ssh into it. I also installed openvpn and configured it so that clients get internet access through the vpn server. The vpn clients get ips from the 10.8.0.0/24 network.

What I want to do now is to allow all the servers from 172.20.0.0/14 to ping/ssh/etc into the vpn clients that are on 10.8.0.0/24 network.

I figured out that I need to make openvpn server push some routes to the clients (in order for the clients to know about the other network);

I am pretty sure that I need to do something on the proxmox host itself (because there is the gateway for the 172.20.0.0/14 network) and I believe that I also have to add some iptable rules on the openvpn server itself in order to forward/masquerade the traffic between the networks but I can't understand exactly what rules.

So my question is: what do I need to do to allow the vpn clients to access the virtual servers given this setup ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a firewall on the OpenVPN host, it will default to permitting traffic, so you can ignore that.

The clients need to have routes pushed to them to ensure traffic destined for the internal subnet is routed over the VPN. This could be a default route (causing ALL traffic to be sent over the VPN from the clients) or a specific route for your internal subnet. You've identified you can push this in the VPN configuration (provided you use certificate-based auth).

You need to enable IP forwarding on the OpenVPN host. Use `sysctl` to set the value of `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding` to 1. Add a file to `/etc/sysctl.d` to ensure this persists across restarts.

The local hosts also require routes to ensure they know how to access the OpenVPN subnet. You could either:

- Use NAT in the OpenVPN host to cause forwarded packets to appear to come from its internal IP. This hides the existence of the 10.8.0.0/24 subnet, and therefore obviates the requirement for any other devices to know about it, but means all traffic from all VPN clients appears to originate from a single host.
- Set up routes to ensure traffic destined for 10.8.0.0/24 is directed to the OpenVPN host. These can be added on each VM or on the host machine. Use the `route` tool, and add commands to your network interface declarations to ensure they persist across reboots.

Comment: I've added a route on the host using route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.21.114.19 but now my internet access is lost :(